# How to envelope a non periodical signal?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scipy, signal-processing

I want to analyse a trc oscilloscope file, find impulses and envelope them. In the end I want to plot the envelope.

data file (trc): https://ufile.io/z4m4d

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import readTrc
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import hilbert

#Read trc file
datX, datY, m = readTrc.readTrc('C220180104_ch2_UHF00014.trc')
srx, sry = pd.Series(datX * 1000), pd.Series(datY * 1000)
df = pd.concat([srx, sry], axis = 1)
df.set_index(0, inplace = True)

#Impulse location
x1 = df[1].idxmax() - 0.0005        #numeric used to show area before impulse
x2 = df[1].idxmax() + 0.003         #numeric used to show area after impulse
df2 = df.loc[x1:x2]

#Locate Maximum
print('Maximum at:', round(df[1].idxmax(), 6), 'ms')

#Plot Impulse (abs)
df3 = df2.abs().interpolate()
df3.plot.area(grid = 1,
              linewidth = 0.5)

#Envelope
signal = hilbert(df2)
envelope = np.abs(signal)
df4 = pd.DataFrame(envelope)
df4.plot(color = 'red')

plt.xlabel('Zeit / ms')
plt.ylabel('UHF-Signal / mV')

##plt.savefig('UHF_plot.png', dpi = 600)
plt.show()

print('done')
```

The Output does not look like an envelope.

Plot:

[image]

Envelope:

[image]

**Edit:**

This is an approximation of what I want.

[image]

Comment: What defines an "envelope"? How should your resulting plot look like?

Comment: Like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(waves), The hilbert function is supposed to do that but it seems to work only with periodical signals.

Comment: Yes, usually you need a treashold frequency to define what an envelope is. What frequency would that be in your case. Or alternatively, you can draw a picture of what you would expect.

Comment: I have uploaded an image. Please take a look at the edit section.

Comment: After thinking about this a bit, I'm now convinced that there is little you can do to achieve the desired curve via filtering. An easy envelope can be achieved with [scipy.ndimage.filters.maximum_filter1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.maximum_filter1d.html), but that would look [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozT0Z.png). Hence one would probably rather *fit*  a certain function to the pulse, or filter it, but without necessarily getting an envelope.

Comment: Also, maybe [signal processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com) might be a better place to ask for the general strategy of obtaining an envelope of a noisy, non-periodic signal.

Answer (score 0):

Envelope demodulation requires bandpassing before the hilbert transform. For your case, I believe that low-passing your "envelope signal" will bring you to the required result.
You can also create an semi-envelope using [find_peaks](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html) but I assume that it was not your intention.